# KO: Error when parsing JSON

Tags: python, json, django, rest, knockout.js

Created a JSBin that demostrated the problem: http://jsbin.com/kukehoj/1/edit?html,js,console,output

I'm creating my first REST-powered website. The backend is in Python (Django REST Framework), and seems to be working fine. I'm trying to make the front-end get the comments for the posts, but its not working.

HTML Imports

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

scripts.js

```
function Comment(data) {
    this.body = ko.observable(data.responseText)
}

function Post(data) {
    this.title = ko.observable(data.title)
    this.body = ko.observable(data.body)

    var self = this;
    self.comments = ko.observableArray([])  

    self.comments(($.map(data.comments, function(link) { // Map the data from
        return $.getJSON(link, function(data) { return new Comment(data)}) //These requests
    })))
}


function PostViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.posts = ko.observableArray([])  

    // Get the posts and map them to a mappedData array. 

    $.getJSON("/router/post/?format=json", function(allData) {
        var mappedData = $.map(allData, function(data) { return new Post(data)})
        self.posts(mappedData)
    })
}


ko.applyBindings(new PostViewModel());
```

Server data:

```
[{  "title":"-->Title here<--",
    "body":"-->Body here<--",
    "comments":[
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/router/comment/6/?format=json",
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/router/comment/7/?format=json",
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/router/comment/8/?format=json",
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/router/comment/9/?format=json"]
}]
```

where each of the links leeds to:

```
{"body":"-->Body here<--"}
```

index.html

```
<div class="col-lg-7" data-bind="foreach: { data: posts, as: 'posts' }">

    <h3 data-bind="text: title"></h3> 
    <p data-bind="text: body"> </p>

    <span data-bind="foreach: { data: comments(), as: 'comments' }"> 
         <p data-bind="text: comments.body"></p>
    </span>

</div>
```

(There is a lot more HTML, but i removed the irrelevant parts)

Everything is working fine, except from that the comments seem to be in the wrong format.

The chrome console shows JSON "responseText" bound to each of the comment object values.

[Wrong format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edogq.png)

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I have tried everything - but it doesn't work. (I'm a noob)

Comment: what is the wrong format like ?

Comment: Added a screenshoot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your sample code you provided except the part you have `this.body = ko.observable(data.responseText)` while your data does not contain a `responseText` in your sample `commentData` object . if you replace `commentData` object  with `var commentData = {"responseText":"-->Body here<--"}` it works.

Note:  this part

```
 <span data-bind="foreach: { data: comments(), as: 'comments' }"> 
         <p data-bind="text: comments.body"></p> // comments.body => body
    </span>
```

on your question is wrong but you have it correct on your sample code .It should be

```
 <span data-bind="foreach: { data: comments(), as: 'comments' }"> 
         <p data-bind="text: body"></p>
    </span>
```

Here is a working version of your sample :https://jsfiddle.net/rnhkv840/26/

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Django Rest Framework, so the JSON structure you get for your posts is done automatically by your serializer based on your model fields.

Back to the frontend, I have not used knockout js before, but what you require is to load the comments using another controller. Either you do it one by one using the links provided by your main resource (this can result in lots of queries sometimes), or you create a filter on your comments endpoint which will allow you to retrieve comments for a specific post.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could try doing it in the backend. So your suggestion is creating a new serializer that handles it?

Comment: You don't need another serializer, you may already have one for your comments. What you need is to extend the list view of your comments.

Comment: You have to add a filter_class: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#overriding-the-initial-queryset

You may also take a look at the **ProductFilter** filter to see how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Ever considered using the django REST framework? It can help you serialize all you models with a simple viewset. Check out the [docs.](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

Answer (score 0):

So found the actual problem. The way the JavaScript read the data from the server, ment that since there was only one value for the comments, the data property of a comment was the variable storing the body of the comment. Not the data.body.